# Delete rows of Numpy Array that contain combinations of certain numbers

Tags: python, numpy

i have an Array containing faces of a triangulation that looks like this:

```
faces = np.array([[4, 0, 1],
                  [5, 4, 1],
                  [7, 5, 1],
                  [7, 5, 4],
                  [3, 0, 1],  # row to delete
                  [7, 3, 1],
                  [4, 2, 0],
                  [6, 4, 2],
                  [7, 6, 2],
                  [7, 6, 4],
                  [3, 2, 0],  # row to delete
                  [7, 3, 2]])
```

Each number in the entry describes a 3-dimensional vertice.
Now i want to delete rows only containing **combinations** of following list:
`indices = [0, 1, 2, 3]`

How could i do this? I have tried some options, however i can't delete just the two faces that i wish to delete.

Comment: are the 3 values in a row necessarily different?

Comment: Please clearly define "combinations of [0 1 2 3]"

Comment: The 3 values in each row reference a row in an array for the vertices of the resulting stl, therefore i would say they are different.

Comment: combinations refers to any possible combination of the four entries of the list, that would result in three entries for each row without appearing twice. Say [0 1 2] or [3 1 2] for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have unique elements in each row, you could use:

```
faces_filtered = faces[~np.isin(faces, indices).all(1)]
```

output (initial rows 4 and 10 have been removed):

```
array([[4, 0, 1],
       [5, 4, 1],
       [7, 5, 1],
       [7, 5, 4],
       [7, 3, 1],
       [4, 2, 0],
       [6, 4, 2],
       [7, 6, 2],
       [7, 6, 4],
       [7, 3, 2]])
```